# Making a C++ Console App Quiz. Console wont take inputs that contain quotations

Tags: c++, string, console

I'm a beginner learning C++. I have decided to create myself a simple console quiz to help me practice. In **line 3** of the piece of code pasted below is the answer I have assigned for question 2 of my quiz, which is contained in a string. Everything compiles fine but the console doesn't recognize the double quotes in ***string EnterName = "";*** It refuses to acknowledge my correct answer and instead runs my *"That is wrong"* else statement.

I know it has a problem with the double quotes because if I change my answer in the string to something without the quotes, the console takes my input, congratulates me and continues to the next question.

1. string Question_02 = "";
2. getline(cin, Question_02);
3. **string Answer_02 = "string EnterName = "";";**

I would like to be able to type   ***string EnterName = "";*** into the console.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 3):

According to the language rules, `"string EnterName = "";"` is two strings,
`"string EnterName = "` and `";"`.

To make `"` part of the string, and not a delimiter, you have to escape it with a `\` character. You then have your code as

```
string Answer_02 = "string EnterName = \"\";";
```

Comment: AMAZING! Works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help and clear explanation.